# FInd the value of 'n' for $^nC_0-^nC_1+^nC_2+...+(-1)^r.^nC_r=28$

Tags: combinatorics

If $^nC_0-^nC_1+^nC_2+...+(-1)^r.^nC_r=28$. Then find the value of $n$.

Comment: For these type of question where we have alternate positive or negative value , how do we calculate upto 'r' terms

Comment: [Vandermonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) gives $$ \begin{align} \sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{n}{k} &=(-1)^r\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{-1}{r-k}\binom{n}{k}\\ &=(-1)^r\binom{n-1}{r} \end{align} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coefficient of $x^r$ in

$$(1-x)^n (1 + x + x^2 + ...) = (1-x)^{n-1}$$

So for $r \lt n$ it is $$(-1)^r\binom{n-1}{r}$$

Answer (score 2):

The alternating truncated binomial sum has the following closed form
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{r} (-1)^i \binom{n}{r}= (-)^r \binom{n-1}{r}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So we just need to find binomial coeffeicient where $\binom{n-1}{r}=28$ and $r$ is even.

By inspection $ \binom{8}{2} = \binom{8}{6} = 28$ is the only solutions. (You still need to check other values of $r$ to be certain of this).

So the possible solutions are $(n,r)= \color{red}{(9,2)} \text{ & } \color{red}{(9,6)}$.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

$r=1$: $1-n=28 \Rightarrow n=-27$ - not an acceptable answer.

$r=2$: $1-n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=28 \Rightarrow 2-2n+n^2-n=56$

This gives $n^2-3n-54=0$ which has one positive integer root.

But you presumably want an answer that is more general in terms of $r$?

Comment: Yes can I get this answer by some accurate method